# Is there a Stack Exchange site for this question looking for a term for a specific pattern of dates?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was wondering where I should post the following question on Stack Exchange. After much thought - <s>and since there isn't a common Meta site</s> - I decided that here would be a good place <s>to start</s> <sup>migrated from [EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15227/370945)'s meta site</sup>.

> Is there a common name for quirky dates like 22/2/22, 11/11/11, 3/3/33 ...?

In case this is *the* place, feel free to answer the question itself.

---

I have since deleted the linked meta post to reduce redundancy. As someone has asked for it, here's how it looks

[image: Screenshot of the original post on meta El&U]

Comment: What did EL&U meta say? Most of us here won't have 10K on that site so the link isn't going to help us. I suspect if they don't want it that no other site will though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Dates

Comment: Your question is almost a [duplicate of another on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/526645/191178).